# In magento 2 datepicker, how to disable a paritcular dates in frontend?

Tags: magento2, datepicker

frontend

1.app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.html

```
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"   name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

2.app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.js

```
console.log(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.mapping_date); 

var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
var disabledDate =window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.mapping_date;
var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,

                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,

                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                var string = 
                         jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                           return[disabledDate.indexOf(string) 
                                                         == -1 ]
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DatePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };
```

output:

[image]

I have tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates/15400806) to disable date to solve this.

**UPDATE:**

Answer is

```
var disabledDate = 
window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.mapping_date;

beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ disabledDate.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide random date or what?

Comment: ya i want to disable a date when admin submitted in backend  https://prnt.sc/mp018p

Comment: @divyasekar Try this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/rage-delivery-date.html

Comment: thanks, i will check and update u  @G Prathap

Comment: In that extension there is no code for  disable particular dates @G Prathap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can check this class as an exmaple](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/blob/master/SR/DeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/js/view/delivery-date-block.js)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_DeliveryDate/delivery-date-block'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
            if(!format) {
                format = 'yy-mm-dd';
            }
            var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                return parseInt(item, 10);
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                    var $el = $(element);
                    //initialize datetimepicker
                    if(noday) {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax
                        };
                    } else {
                        var options = {
                            minDate: 0,
                            dateFormat:format,
                            hourMin: hourMin,
                            hourMax: hourMax,
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var day = date.getDay();
                                if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                    return [false];
                                } else {
                                    return [true];
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    $el.datetimepicker(options);

                    var writable = valueAccessor();
                    if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                        var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                        if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                            writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    writable($(element).datetimepicker("getDate"));
                },
                update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
                    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                    if (widget) {
                        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                        widget.date(date);
                    }
                }
            };

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i already check this. its have a disable days.. i need to disable a array of dates

Comment: No worries, write more with an example what you want.